# MongoDB Query Timing difference from shell and Android mobile

Tags: android, mongodb, indexing

I'm using mongodb for my mobile application to store the data's. When i connect to the mongo server thro RoboMongo and query with `explain("executionStats")` it says

```
{
    "cursor" : "IDCursor",
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [ 
            [ 
                ObjectId("5592a10d634a61834f354f3b"), 
                ObjectId("5592a10d634a61834f354f3b")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "h003744.mongolab.com:55690"
}
```

and the millis are 0. When i put the same query in my android application without explain command it takes 4 to 5 sec to get the result even though i'm using index in this query.

What is the mistake i'm doing here.

**EDIT :**

**JAVA CODE**

```
BasicDBObject user = new BasicDBObject(TripsConstants._ID, new ObjectId(id));
BasicDBObject show = new BasicDBObject(TripsConstants._ID, 0).append(TripsConstants.USER_EMAIL, 1).append(TripsConstants.TOTAL_TIME, 1)
                    .append(TripsConstants.TRIP_DESCRIPTION, 1).append(TripsConstants.TOTAL_DISTANCE, 1).append(TripsConstants.TRIP_RATES, 1)
                    .append(TripsConstants.TRIP_COMMENTS, 1);
BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) coll.findOne(user, show);
```

**SHELL QUERY**

```
db.getCollection('trip_details').find({_id : ObjectId("5592a10d634a61834f354f3b")},{ "_id" : 0 , "user_email" : 1 , "total_time" : 1 , "trip_description" : 1 , "total_distance" : 1 , "trip_rates" : 1 , "trip_comments" : 1 , "start_point" : 1 , "end_point" : 1 , "pause_point" : 1 , "resume_point" : 1 , "waypoints" : 1 , "waypoint_notes" : 1 , "waypoint_images" : 1 , "geometry" : 1})
```

**INDEXES IN MONGODB**

```
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "new_model.trip_details"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "trip_name_text_waypoint_notes.notes_text_trip_description_text_waypoints.waypoint_name_text",
        "ns" : "new_model.trip_details",
        "weights" : {
            "trip_description" : 1,
            "trip_name" : 1,
            "waypoint_notes.notes" : 1,
            "waypoints.waypoint_name" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "geometry" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "geometry_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "new_model.trip_details",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    "3" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "user_email" : 1.0000000000000000
        },
        "name" : "user_email_1",
        "ns" : "new_model.trip_details"
    }
}
```

Comment: How should we know without a single line of code?

Comment: what code you need.?
I'm just asking that query from application is slow than query in shell

Comment: I have understood your question. I need the query on the shell and the according one in Java to find out wether they are equal. Furthermore, I need all indices. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment let me add the query..!!!!!!

Comment: I believe you can add ".explain()" to the Java query and get back the statistics of the execution. This way you can identify if the same index is hit. If the shell you are connected to is on a remote server and the device is connecting over GSM, Wifi there will be latency, however, 4-5 seconds seems excessive. I would also remove the server key from your example ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i've posted the code can you check these